# Usage of "on" in the phrase "on our team"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions

Is the following sentence grammatically correct:
"Alice on our team has been excellent in managing tasks."

I'd rather substitute "from" or "in" instead of the "on" in this sentence. Can someone please help me understand which usage is correct in this example.

Comment: What leads you to believe that "on" may be incorrect?

Comment: That construct sounds odd anyway...I'd say it like this: "Our team member, Alice, has been excellent in managing tasks."

Comment: It is the use of prepositions that most distinguishes American and British forms of the language. In America one appears *on a team*, or has eleven players *on our team*. In Britain we find ourselves *in the team for the match on Saturday.How many players are there **in** a rugby team?*

Comment: @MattGutting The on usage plainly sounded odd.

Comment: I might have said *On our team, Alice has been ...*, or perhaps *Alice, who's on our team, has been ...* But it sounds fine to me.

Comment: @WS2 I did suspect the differences in AmE and BrE usage as the culprit for the oddity here. "On" makes it appear as if alice is "sitting" on the team. I'd like to believe Matt's opinion though due to my lil' inclination toward AmE usage.

Comment: *From our team* would also be an acceptable American English phrasing.

Comment: I wish people would make some effort to check before posting what they feel the true situation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepositional usage is idiosyncratic, with even apparently near-identical structures not being similarly available.

Both *on our team* and *in our team* are grammatical and used; *on our team* seems to be the more common choice according to [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+our+team%2Con+our+team&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20our%20team%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20our%20team%3B%2Cc0) (though the two seem equally common in British works).

There are over 300 000 Google hits for both *everyone on our team* and *everyone in our team* (though Ngrams paint a different picture). But I'm quite familiar with this type of post-modifier; neither prepositional usage can be considered incorrect.

Comment: I am marking your response as the answer. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, a lot of non-natives would prefer "in". But English says "on the team / on the staff".

"On + person group" meaning someone is a member of this group is a special niche of on every learner stumbles on.

Why this curious use? Some uses of on are really hard to explain. I can only give my guess. The underlying idea seems to be "someone was elected or taken on as a member".

Ultimately you have to learn this special use of on.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I agree that it is the non-nativity with AmE that could raise doubts on the usage.